# I can't Save Multiple PlayerPrefs on my Main Menu

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm a student in game development, making a game where players can grab certain amounts of coins on each maps, every maps has different type of coins data, like a highscore. But it only saves 1 playerprefs only. Why is that happening?

**This is my Scene Management Script;**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class changeScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI desertCoinAmount;
    public TextMeshProUGUI plainsCoinAmount;

    void Update()
    {
        desertCoinAmount.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("DesertCoins").ToString();
        plainsCoinAmount.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlainsCoins").ToString();
    }

    public void mainMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("mainMenu");
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    public void desertLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("ancientDesertLEVEL");
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
    public void plainsLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Plain Biome");
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
    
    public void jungleLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Jungle Biome");
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
    }
}
```

**And This is my PlayerController;**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject winPopup, losePopup;
    public GameObject heart1, heart2, heart3;
    public float gravityScale = 10f;
    private Rigidbody rb;
    public TextMeshProUGUI coinText;
    public AudioSource coinSound;

    int coin_sumDesert;
    int coin_sumPlains;
    int life_sum = 3;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Physics.gravity * gravityScale, ForceMode.Force);
    }

   void Update()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("DesertCoins", coin_sumDesert);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlainsCoins", coin_sumPlains); 
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Coins")
        {
            coin_sumDesert++;
            coinText.text = coin_sumDesert.ToString();
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            coinSound.Play();
            
        }
        
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "PlainsCoins")
        {
            coin_sumPlains++;
            coinText.text = coin_sumPlains.ToString();
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            coinSound.Play();
            
        }
        
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "finishLine")
        {
            winPopup.SetActive(true);
            
        }

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "obstacles")
        {
            Debug.Log("Collide Detected");
            life_sum--;
            if (life_sum == 2)
            {
                heart1.SetActive(false);
            }
            else if (life_sum == 1)
            {
                heart2.SetActive(false);
            }
            else if (life_sum == 0)
            {
                heart3.SetActive(false);

                losePopup.SetActive(true);
                Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate the reply (this is my first time using StackOverflow xD)

Comment: [THE PLAYERPREFES LEVEL](https://imgur.com/a/3KZlsOb) 

If i finish the second level, first level data will be 0 or deleted. If i finish 2nd level it only save the second level data (coin).

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple `PlayerController` then obviously they write to the same `PlayerPrefs` keys.

Whenever you save a player's data, make sure you differentiate them e.g. Score1, Score2, etc.

This is a way among many others to achieve it:

The player, very simple, append index to player pref to differentiate among many:

```
public sealed class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string ChocolateBarsKey = "ChocolateBars";

    [SerializeField]
    [HideInInspector]
    private int Index;

    private int ChocolateBars
    {
        get => GetInt(ChocolateBarsKey);
        set => SetInt(ChocolateBarsKey, value);
    }

    private int GetInt([NotNull] string key, int defaultValue = default)
    {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));

        return PlayerPrefs.GetInt($"{key}{Index}", defaultValue);
    }

    private void SetInt([NotNull] string key, int value)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt($"{key}{Index}", value);
    }

    [NotNull]
    internal static Player Create([NotNull] GameObject parent, int index)
    {
        if (parent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parent));

        var controller = parent.AddComponent<Player>();

        controller.name  = $"{nameof(Player)} {index}";
        controller.Index = index;

        return controller;
    }
}
```

The factory, scriptable singleton won't lose state on assembly reload, whereas if you'd used a static `int` for player count, it would reset itself to zero at assembly reload because static fields are not serialized by Unity.

```
public sealed class PlayerFactory : ScriptableSingleton<PlayerFactory>
{
    [SerializeField]
    private int PlayerCount;

    [NotNull]
    public Player Create(GameObject parent)
    {
        return Player.Create(parent, ++PlayerCount);
    }
}
```

Now if you don't want to store score data within `Player`, it'll be another pattern. I leave that to you as an exercise.